# I don't know what's wrong with contact form

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, contacts

I'm new to web development, and i need help with this contact form.
I'm using a bootstrap template.

Sorry guys for posting mistakes, I'm new here, and i i'm a little confused about posting and editing.

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $message = $_POST['message']);
        // $human = intval($_POST['human']);
        $from = 'Demo Contact Form'; 
        $to = 'info@artgate.me'; 
        $subject = 'Message from Contact Demo ';

        $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

        // Check if name has been entered
        if (!$_POST['name']) {
            $errName = 'Please enter your name';
        }

        // Check if email has been entered and is valid
        if (!$_POST['email'] || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $errEmail = 'Please enter a valid email address';
        }

        //Check if message has been entered
        if (!$_POST['message']) {
            $errMessage = 'Please enter your message';
        }
        //Check if simple anti-bot test is correct
        //if ($human !== 5) {
         //   $errHuman = 'Your anti-spam is incorrect';
        }

// If there are no errors, send the email
if (!$errName && !$errEmail && !$errMessage) {
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
        $result='<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! I will be in touch</div>';
    } else {
        $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later</div>';
    }
}
    }
?>
```

**JS Code**

```
function contactForm(){
  $('.btn-submit').on('click',function(e){
        var $this = $(this);

        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url  : 'contact.php',
            type : 'POST',
            data : $this.closest('.contact-form').serialize(),
            success : function(data){
                if ($(data).is('.send-true')){
                    $this.addClass('loading').delay(650).queue(function(){
                        $this.addClass('success').addClass('loaded').dequeue();
                    });
                } else {
                    $this.addClass('error');
                }

                $this.delay(500).queue(function(){
                    $this.removeClass('loaded').removeClass('loading').dequeue();
                });

                $this.delay(400).queue(function(){
                    if ($(data).is('.send-true')){
                        $this.removeClass('success').closest('.contact-form').trigger('reset');
                    } else {
                        $this.removeClass('error');
                    }
                    $this.dequeue();
                });
            }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: LOL.... your PHP code is actually JS code..... post your PHP code please ... the code of `contact.php`

Comment: What is the error in the console ?

Comment: Or try `success : function(data){ console.log(data)` and see what is in console?

Comment: is it your complete PHP code? I cannot see any line which actually sends the email

Comment: What is the "name" property of your submit button?

Comment: @sambo613 the button property  is .btn-submit

Comment: @AliAl-Arabi, No, not the class name. I am wondering about what this is `name = " "` for the button.

Comment: @sambo613  here is the button :     <button type="submit" data-hover="Send" class="btn btn-default progress-button btn-submit"><span class="button-label">Send</span></button>

Answer (score 0):

try changing your php from this:

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
```

to this:

```
if (isset($_POST["btn-submit"])) {
```

If you named your submit button "btn-submit" then your POST will contain a variable called "btn-submit"

Answer (score 0):

In the comments, you said that your HTML code for your button was this:

```
<button type="submit" data-hover="Send" class="btn btn-default progress-button btn-submit"><span class="button-label">Send</span></button>
```

What you need is a "Name" property. So it should look like this:

```
<button type="submit" data-hover="Send" name="sendform" class="btn btn-default progress-button btn-submit"><span class="button-label">Send</span></button>
```

Once you edit that, you need to change

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
```

To

```
if (isset($_POST["sendform"])) {
```

This should make it work now.

Comment: Did you printed/echo "$result" variable after initializing it ?
can you try at the end of the PHP file and see if response is coming: 
echo  $result; 
die;

Answer (score -1):

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {

To
if (isset($_POST["submit_button_name"])) {

then i will work for you i think